# Codeigniter handle database error without num_rows()

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm having trouble finding a simple method for handling database errors in CI. For instance, I can't insert duplicate entries in my database table. If I try to, I get a `1062` database error.

The most common solution suggested is to check if the entry already exists and use

`$query->num_rows() > 0`

in a if-statement to prevent an error. That method seems redundant to me because I'm performing an extra query. Ideally I want to check if an error occurs in my main query or if a row is affected.

I found the following functions that may help

```
$this->db->affected_rows()

$this->db->_error_message()
```

however I'm not sure how to use them.

I tried in my Model:

```
$this->db->insert('subscription', $data);
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

To my understanding that should return the number of effected rows. Then in my controller I added:

```
$affected = $this->Subscribe_model->subscribe($data);

if ($affected < 1)
{
    //display error message in view
}
else
{
   $this->Subscribe_model->subscribe($data); //perform query
}
```

Unfortunately the script stops in the model at `$this->db->insert('subscription', $data);` if an error occurs and displays the entire database error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@$this->db->insert('subscription', $data);`, `@`, in PHP means "suppress warning".

As an alternate -- if you know that data is safe, or you're willing to use `$this->db->insert_string`, you could add, `on duplicate key` to the end of the query.

This should work (untested):

```
$this->db->simple_query( $this->db->insert_string( 'subscription', $data ) . 
                            ' ON DUPLICATE KEY ' . 
                            $this->db->update_string( 
                                        'subscription', 
                                         $data, 
                                         /* your where clause here */ );
```

Comment: Thanks! Would `IGNORE` in the query also be a good solution? I'm trying to keep db queries minimal, should a duplicate row already exist.

Comment: Sure, I would just do `str_replace( 'INSERT', 'INSERT IGNORE', $this->db->insert_string( 'subscription', $data ) );`

Comment: You can also use `query` for this. `simple_query`, while useful for times when you want minimal processing, does not do as much as `query` does.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this works for `$this->db->insert();`, but `$this->db->query();` will return false if it errors so you could do something like this:

```
$sql = $this->db->insert_string('subscription', $data);
$sql = $this->db->query($sql)
if(!$sql){
    //Do your error handling here
} else {
    //query ran successfully
}
```